# getModel attributeToFilter overridden by server default status?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection, query

I'm trying to get all the products where the `qty` is above 0 and `is_in_stock` on 1.
But when i'm trying to use the following code it overrides the `addAttributeToFilter`.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
    ->joinField(
        'qty',
        'cataloginventory/stock_item',
        'qty',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        '{{table}}.is_in_stock=1',
        'left'
    )
    ->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array('gt' => 0));
```

This code should return (on development server):

```
SELECT `e`.*, `at_qty`.`qty` 
FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `at_qty` ON (at_qty.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND (at_qty.is_in_stock=1)
WHERE (at_qty.qty > 0)
```

but instead it returns (on live server):

```
SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `at_qty`.`qty`
FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e`
LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `at_qty` ON (at_qty.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND (at_qty.is_in_stock=1)
WHERE (e.status = 1)
```

**EDIT:**

For some reason the `WHERE` part is overridden and changed to e.status

Any help would be appreciated.

**FINAL EDIT**

Because of the awesome research @Jaimin I was able to solve my problem.
Both development and live were on yes in this setting:

> System > Configuration > Catalog > Frontend > Use Flat Catalog Product

So both returned values from `catalog_product_flat_1`.

after using the following getModel instead:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
     ->getCollection()
     ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id');
$collection->getSelect()->join(
array('stock_item'=>'cataloginventory_stock_item'),
 '`stock_item`.`product_id` = `e`.`entity_id`', 
 array('qty', 'is_in_stock'));
```

and using the following to add `qty` and `is_in_stock` to the `where` part of the sql:

```
$collection->getSelect()->where('is_in_stock = ?', 1);
$collection->getSelect()->where('qty > ?', 0);
```

It was able to show  me the correct data.

Comment: Did you check if flat catalog is enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add quantity filter to your collection, you can use below code.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id, qty')
->joinField(
    'qty2',
    'cataloginventory/stock_item',
    'qty2',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    '{{table}}.is_in_stock=1' ,
    'left'
);
$collection->getSelect()->where('qty > 0');
```

The issue with removing `qty` from query string seems to be related to Magento's Flat catalog functionality.

> System > Configuration > Catalog > Frontend > Use Flat Catalog Product

On your development server, Flat catalog in disabled so Magento makes a request to product's original table `catalog_product_entity`

```
SELECT `e`.*, `at_qty`.`qty` 
FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `at_qty` ON (at_qty.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND (at_qty.is_in_stock=1)
WHERE (at_qty.qty > 0)
```

On your live server, Flat catalog is enabled that's why it makes a request to Magento's flat table `catalog_product_flat_1`

```
SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `at_qty`.`qty`
FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e`
LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `at_qty` ON (at_qty.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND (at_qty.is_in_stock=1)
WHERE (e.status = 1)
```

Now for not using `qty` attribute in flat table query, I have debug the issue a little and I found below.

When you use `addAttributeToFilter` on product collection, it calls the function 
`Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::addAttributeToFilter($attribute, $condition = null, $joinType = 'inner')`

```
public function addAttributeToFilter($attribute, $condition = null, $joinType = 'inner')
{
    if ($this->isEnabledFlat()) {
        if ($attribute instanceof Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract) {
            $attribute = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
        }

        if (is_array($attribute)) {
            $sqlArr = array();
            foreach ($attribute as $condition) {
                $sqlArr[] = $this->_getAttributeConditionSql($condition['attribute'], $condition, $joinType);
            }
            $conditionSql = '('.join(') OR (', $sqlArr).')';
            $this->getSelect()->where($conditionSql);
            return $this;
        }

        if (!isset($this->_selectAttributes[$attribute])) {
            $this->addAttributeToSelect($attribute);
        }

        if (isset($this->_selectAttributes[$attribute])) {
            $this->getSelect()->where($this->_getConditionSql('e.' . $attribute, $condition));
        }

        return $this;
    }

    $this->_allIdsCache = null;

    if (is_string($attribute) && $attribute == 'is_saleable') {
        $columns = $this->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
        foreach ($columns as $columnEntry) {
            list($correlationName, $column, $alias) = $columnEntry;
            if ($alias == 'is_saleable') {
                if ($column instanceof Zend_Db_Expr) {
                    $field = $column;
                } else {
                    $adapter = $this->getSelect()->getAdapter();
                    if (empty($correlationName)) {
                        $field = $adapter->quoteColumnAs($column, $alias, true);
                    } else {
                        $field = $adapter->quoteColumnAs(array($correlationName, $column), $alias, true);
                    }
                }
                $this->getSelect()->where("{$field} = ?", $condition);
                break;
            }
        }

        return $this;
    } else {
        return parent::addAttributeToFilter($attribute, $condition, $joinType);
    }
}
```

Here you can see line `if ($this->isEnabledFlat()) {` this checks if Flat catalog in enabled from admin panel.
In this code, it will check

```
if (!isset($this->_selectAttributes[$attribute])) {
    $this->addAttributeToSelect($attribute);
}
```

Here it checks current attribute to filter (in your case `qty`) if it exists in `$this->_selectAttributes`

This variable is set in function in the same file.

```
public function addAttributeToSelect($attribute, $joinType = false)
{
    if ($this->isEnabledFlat()) {
        if (!is_array($attribute)) {
            $attribute = array($attribute);
        }
        foreach ($attribute as $attributeCode) {
            if ($attributeCode == '*') {
                foreach ($this->getEntity()->getAllTableColumns() as $column) {
                    $this->getSelect()->columns('e.' . $column);
                    $this->_selectAttributes[$column] = $column;
                    $this->_staticFields[$column]     = $column;
                }
            } else {
                $columns = $this->getEntity()->getAttributeForSelect($attributeCode);
                if ($columns) {
                    foreach ($columns as $alias => $column) {
                        $this->getSelect()->columns(array($alias => 'e.' . $column));
                        $this->_selectAttributes[$column] = $column;
                        $this->_staticFields[$column]     = $column;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
    return parent::addAttributeToSelect($attribute, $joinType);
}
```

Here it checks `$columns = $this->getEntity()->getAttributeForSelect($attributeCode);`

for `qty`, this returns `false` because there is no `qty` column in table `catalog_product_flat_1` and it removes `qty` from query string.

Comment: Hi @Jaimin Thanks for your explanation and research. I've looked into the `System > ... > Use flat catalog product`, it seems like both (on development and live) are on Yes. After debugging the getCollection model it should return data from the table  `catalog_product_flat_1` (which it did). Now i've added this line: `$collection->getSelect()->where('qty > 0');` to the query by using a normal `getSelect->join()`. This returns the correct data. Your answer is awesome. Thanks again. I've added extra data to my question how i've solved the problem.